# How can a find a bottle/nipple that our infant will accept

Tags: bottle-feeding

[How can we make our newborn accept the bottle?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-we-make-our-newborn-accept-the-bottle)

I know this a related question but we can't afford to swapping and changing in Japan- they are expensive here. Our 5 month takes one mouthful of the bottle milk and won't drink any more whether its expressed or formula- he is all breast feed but it would nice to have the  option when my wife is sore from the posture she uses when normally feeding.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few other options than just switching brands - you can use a spoon, a beaker or a sippy cup to feed your baby. At five months you either have already done or probably will soon start with solid foods and these tools are going to be part of your equipment anyway. Some exclusively breastfed babies simoly dislike baby bottles, but readily accept the alternatives above.

And even though we don't question the premise of a question here, in this case I suggest that your wife *additionally* re-evaluates her nursing technique. Soreness happens, yes, but some negative side effects of nursing can and should be avoided. A lactation consultant, midwife or similar might be a good first source of information.

Comment: Thanks for you reply- the issue isn't really of nipples and milk supply rather a woman who has never done any strengthening exercises plus unwilling to not kneel- she has some cushion supports, a some times greedy and night-time active baby and some times not eating baby-so he isn't gaining enough weight. Its about back pain.

Comment: @user2617804 trust me - I can feel with her. And I wasn't refering to sore nipples alone. Body posture is almost as much of an influence to successful nursing than the "usual suspects" of proper latch and nipple soreness. A good consultant should be able to help with good positioning of *the mother* as well.

Comment: we tried many bottles with no success.  He wanted the real thing.  Different postures and pillows helped and the ideal postures changed as the baby grew.  At first, a large pillow that hooked around the waist was very useful.  Wearing baby in a sling or carrier with baby upright also worked great and once baby and mom were used to it allowed mom to continue doing whatever else she was doing.  Maybe I am thinking of this wrong, but kneeling seems like the worst possible approach for back pain.